# How to query the JSON using JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql-server

JSON input:

```
[
  {
    "InputType":"Date",
    "InputName":"Main_Expiry_Date",
    "InputValue":"30 June 2020"
  },
  {
    "InputType":"Select",
    "InputName":"Internet_Service_Providers",
    "InputValue":"NTC"
  },
  {
    "InputType":"Select",
    "InputName":"Link_Desc",
    "InputValue":"Primary"
  },
  {
    "InputType":"TextBox",
    "InputName":"Remarks",
    "InputValue":""
  }
]
```

Comment: Please show us your research and attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to parse this JSON array using `JSON_VALUE()`, you should use the following statement:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = 
N'[
  {"InputType":"Date", "InputName":"Main_Expiry_Date", "InputValue":"30 June 2020"},
  {"InputType":"Select", "InputName":"Internet_Service_Providers", "InputValue":"NTC"},
  {"InputType":"Select", "InputName":"Link_Desc", "InputValue":"Primary"},
  {"InputType":"TextBox", "InputName":"Remarks", "InputValue":""}
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.InputType') AS InputType,
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.InputName') AS InputName,
   JSON_VALUE([value], '$.InputValue') AS InputValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

Result:

```
InputType   InputName                   InputValue
Date        Main_Expiry_Date            30 June 2020
Select      Internet_Service_Providers  NTC
Select      Link_Desc                   Primary
TextBox     Remarks
```

Note, that you may parse the input JSON using `OPENJSON()` with an explicit schema, without using `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT InputType, InputName, InputValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   InputType varchar(50) '$.InputType', 
   InputName varchar(50) '$.InputName', 
   InputValue varchar(50) '$.InputValue'
)
```